# How to query SOLR with 98,000 ids without getting maxBooleanClause exception

Tags: mysql, database, solr, solrj

Our Spring Java website's MySql database has got the following tables

- CUSTOMER
- PRODUCT
- PRODUCT_CUSTOMER_XREF (Customers who bought a product)
- CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_XREF (Customers who are friends with other customer)

in SOLR we've indexed all PRODUCTS which have a unique id which is PRODUCT_ID.

My job

- Display PRODUCTS current logged in CUSTOMER's friends bought in the past.
- Let customer search for product descriptions and product reviews of Customers friends done in that past

***Steps I used***

- **SQL Query** Get friends of current logged in CUSTOMER ( returns 500 CUSTOMERS)
- **JOIN SQL QUERY** Get the PRODUCT(s) purchased by every friend CUSTOMER (returns 98,000 PRODUCTS_ID). This could possibly return 500,000
- **SOLR query** id:(1 2 3 4 5 ....98000) returns maxBooleanClause exception.
- **MySQL Query** - Get friends of Customer who bought or commented on the returns Product ids.

***Problem*** - solr query

- I cannot query for 98,000+ products in SOLR because this return maxBooleanClause exception. I can increase the maxBoolean in solr-config.xml file but this seems like a bad practice consider this number be in 100 of thousands.
- I can add 98,000+ queries for the same field but this sounds like a bad practice aswell.
- Costly to send 98,000+ ids to SOLR server over HTTP post.

Can someone please help me with a solution ?

**Additional Note**:I was thinking if there is a way I can group all CUSTOMER_IDs who bought or commented on a particular product into 1 number or token or some sort and then check if the logged in CUSTOMER's ID friends IDs belong to that group. But haven't figured out a formula yet.

Comment: how many records do you have in product table?

Comment: It's ridiculously huge. My query returned count of 891,345 PRODUCTS.

Comment: hmm... i was suspecting when "Get the PRODUCT(s) purchased by every friend CUSTOMER" you didn't get the distinct values of product id but since you have about 900K products its quite possible to have 98k distinct products

Comment: Yes, I've just added an additional note to the question. Would something like that work Mathematically ?

Comment: yes it can but with several disadvantages : 1. that token will be rather big if you have many customers grouped 2. the search feature will be slower since you need to "decode" that token in order to get the customers

Comment: but why cant you use a limit ? like pagination ?

Comment: Yep, we are using pagination. Eg: CUSTOMER wants to search for PRODUCTS which CUSTOMER's friends reviewed on with the search keyword "toaster" in this situation say I grab 30 products for my query that logged in CUSTOMER's friends reviewed on, this might stop us from displaying the most relavent 80th PRODUCT with review keyword "toaster".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this ...

Solr Index

> Person

- Id
- Name
- Friends
- Products_Purchased

> Products

- Id
- Title

  1. 1st Query - `fq=friends:id&facet.field=Products_Purchased`
  2. This would limit the results to only the Persons, the User is friend with
  3. Also the facet on the products purchased, would be Order by the Count of the Products
  4. This will also make sure you have unique ids for Products.
  5. 2nd Query - I would use these Ids to query solr probably in the batch of 20-50 max with pagination.
  6. Pagination is valid for facets as well, so you can Navigate the results.

Comment: I've got the PRODUCT_ID's purchased by Customers's friends but querying the database (No SOLR needed). The problem is to query the database with a large number of PRODUCT_ID's. Querying in batches causes a problem when user is searching for a keyword in the reviews of products his/her friends written about.  Eg: which one of my friends said "Good Toaster" in a review. Batching 50 PRODUCT_ID's would be a problem if the review "Good Toaster" was on the 100th PRODUCT_ID.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can split it on few requests,
it will be better than retrieve all items per one request.

But I maybe be better switch to another approach :)

you can store customers who buy this item in Solr too.

So your plan will be changed on:

SQL Query Get friends of current logged in CUSTOMER ( returns 500 CUSTOMERS)
SOLR query customers:(1 2 3 4 5 ....500) with search request.

this requires from you updates Solr when some customer buy or comments item, but you win on READ phase. such as solr query more simple and you don't need to make join request.